# Hot to get set of properties as map with apache commons-configuration and a properties file

Tags: configuration, apache-commons

I would like to as if it is possible/supported by commons-configuration of apache to get from a properties file a property as a map

Up to now I have managed to do this indirectly with the following code snippet

```
 Map<String, T> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 Configuration subset = config.subset(key);
 if (!subset.isEmpty()) {
     Iterator it = subset.getKeys();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
         String k = (String) it.next();
         //noinspection unchecked
         T v = (T) subset.getProperty(k);
         map.put(k, v);
     }
 }
 return map;
```

Does anyone knows a more straight forward way than this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

I prefer how you did it but if you like: [ConfigurationMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/ConfigurationMap.html)

```
Map<Object,Object> config = new ConfigurationMap(subset);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get all properties as Map with apache commons confuguration2

```
Parameters params = new Parameters();
File propertiesFile = new File("properties.properties");
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder =
                new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                        .configure(params.fileBased()
                        .setFile(propertiesFile)
                        .setEncoding("UTF-8"));

Configuration config = builder.getConfiguration();
Map<Object,Object> cfg = new ConfigurationMap(config);
cfg.entrySet();
```

to check out:

```
for (Map.Entry entry : cfg.entrySet()) {
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
}
```